# Sphinx documentation set meta directive (description based on page content) in conf.py

Tags: python-sphinx

Sphinx has this [meta directive](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#html-metadata) but it need to be be added manually in each RST document.

```
.. meta::
   :description: The Sphinx documentation builder
   :keywords: Sphinx, documentation, builder
```

I would like to set meta description using conf.py in one global config file.

There is an extension [sphinxext-opengraph](https://pypi.org/project/sphinxext-opengraph/) with option to return description text with configurable amount of characters taken for the page using `ogp_description_length`

I wonder if it can be used to achieve this for meta description.

Thanks in advance.